# UnityWebRequest.Put doesn't send JSON string

Tags: javascript, c#, api, unity-game-engine, vercel

I'm looking to make a PUT or POST request to an API I've deployed to Vercel built with NEXT JS. It does other things besides being an API but that's not important...

So, I have a Unity Project where I would like to log the time that my player completed the level they're on.
Originally I wanted to use Firebase but discovered that I can't as the Windows Unity builds don't support it so I ended up just making an API that send the Data to MongoDB and does some other stuff, again not important.

So getting to the guts of the problem:

I have this IEnumerator to send the request:

```
IEnumerator logPlayerTime()
{
    string url = "http://some-vercel-cloud-function/api/new";
    var requestBody = new PlayerRequestBody();
    requestBody.firstName = "John";
    requestBody.lastName = "Doe";
    requestBody.email = "email@email.com";
    requestBody.marketing = false;
    requestBody.time = 200000;  // this actually come from somewhere else but for now this is fine

    string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(requestBody);

    UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Put(url, json);
    request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.SetRequestHeader("Accept", "*/*");
    request.SetRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
    request.SetRequestHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
    request.useHttpContinue = false;
    yield return request.SendWebRequest();

    if (request.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
    {
        Debug.Log(request.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Time Logged! " + json);
    }
}
```

According to the [Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-UploadingRawData.html) I should have two arguments, the first being my URL and the second Being my Data.

As for the JSON I want to send I made this `struct`

```
[Serializable]
private struct PlayerRequestBody
{
    public string firstName;
    public string lastName;
    public string email;
    public bool marketing;
    public float time;
}
```

Then, I'm using `JsonUtiltiy.ToJson` to turn my `json` variable into a JSON string, which seems to work.

All of this said, no matter what I change in the request, even typing the JSON string out manually escaped. It just sends a request body of an empty JSON object like this:

```
{}
```

So if we take a look at what the API receives the logs look like this:

```
[PUT] /api/new    01:44:25:13    {}
```

I'm sure it's something small but I just don't have enough experience with Unity or C# to find the issue (and I want to go to bed).

As for how this gets called, In one of my Scripts that manages the game I have a handler method that is subscribed to GameState changes, so when my GameState === GameState.Victory then I would run the handler. So the code for that, with bits removed for readability looks like this:

```
// ...
private void Awake()
{
    GameManager.OnGameStateChanged += GameManager_OnGameStateChanged;
}
// ...
private void GameManager_OnGameStateChanged(GameState state)
{
    
    if (state == GameState.Victory)
    {
        handleVictory();
    }

}
```

That `handleVictory` method just runs StartCoroutine on the IEnumerator at the moment

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure your json isn’t barfing? And returning an empty string?

Comment: Yeah, I've Debug.Log-ed it and It's a valid JSON string, like I said I've even typed it out manually with escaping etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a trailing / to the url, so your url should be:

```
string url = "http://some-vercel-cloud-function/api/new/";
```

Comment: This is quite an old question however from my experience with backend over the past couple years, yeah I can see that being a thing so I'll take your word for it :)

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone who ever somehow runs into this, the answer is... Next is weird.

I made another API using Express JS and boom instant data from the Player.

I don't have time to look into it but there must be something about Unitys UnityWebRequest that Next doesn't agree with. Long and short I'm gonna pull the API out of next and then move over my components to React and host it on a server less function :)